# Is there any noun or expression can refer to someone who extremly excels in some profession or skills?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for a synonym of word like savvy or veteran but I need another expression , which would have the exact meaning of someone reaches very  high level of mastery of skill or technique and appears with much respect from other people,and I would thank you all for answering!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I suggest you consult an online site such as word hippo, where you can sometimes get scores of synonyms by simply typing in a word and pressing enter! You can also find antonyms as well at the click of a mouse:  https://www.wordhippo.com/

Comment: Use a thesaurus to find synonyms of "expert". I like "viruoso".

Comment: Consider **"MAESTRO"** & **"MAVEN"** , which are quite suitable to OP Case [[ BTW , you have a typo , @Barmar , virtuoso , which is suitable to OP Case too ]]